# Add a new font in tesseract (Windows)

Tags: python, tesseract

Im trying to add a new font in my tesseract-ocr. There was a tool at trainyourtesseract.com where you could upload font and get trained data but it isnt working now. So I searched for it in the net and found they have docs which was overwhelming and confusing cuz the commands were linux based and I didnt understand because Im not too much into tesseract. So is there any simple and quicker way to insert a new font in my tesseract windows? Or any site to guide in simple steps?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I want to do the same.